# validation XML against XSD java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

When I validate my xml online all is good. But when in eclipse it doesn't work. It's return an error:

> SAX Exception: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'file:/C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Task3_XML/Task3_XML/weapon.xml', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

This is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     boolean isValid = validateXMLSchema("weapon.xml","weaponXSD.xml");
     if(isValid){
        System.out.println(args[1] + " is valid against " + args[0]);
     }else {
        System.out.println(args[1] + " is not valid against " + args[0]);
     }
  }


public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){
  try {
     SchemaFactory factory = 
        SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
     Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
  } catch (IOException e){    
     System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
     return false;
  }catch(SAXException e1){
     System.out.println("SAX Exception: "+e1.getMessage());
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Gun>
  <Weapon>
    <Model>Пістолет «Форт-12»</Model>
    <Handy>one-handed</Handy>
    <Origin>Україна</Origin>
    <TTH>
      <carry>близька [0;500 m]</carry>
      <effectiveRange>10 m</effectiveRange>
      <availabilityClips>true</availabilityClips>
      <availabilityOptics>false</availabilityOptics>
    </TTH>
    <Material>метал</Material>
  </Weapon>
</Gun>
```

And my XSD in short form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Gun">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Weapon" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Model">`
```

Please if you have any idea write me because i don't understand where there is a problem really.

Answer (score 1):

The error says

```
file:/C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Task3_XML/Task3_XML/weapon.xml
```

is not an XSD file.

You are passing the `xml` file as first parameter to the method `validateXMLSchema` while it expects as first parameter the `xsd` file.

You need to call that method like this:

```
boolean isValid = validateXMLSchema("weaponXSD.xml", "weapon.xml");
```

Also please change the extension of your schema file to `.xsd`

```
weaponXSD.xsd
```

or simply

```
weapon.xsd
```